# How can std::vector access elements with huge gaps between them?

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, iterator, stdvector

Having this code:

```
template <class IIt, class OIt>
OIt copy2(IIt begin, IIt end, OIt dest)
{
   while (begin != end)
   {
      //make gap between element addresses
      for (int i = 0; i < 99999999; i++)
      {
         dest++;
      }
      *dest++ = *begin++;
   }
   return dest;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   vector<int> vec({ 1, 2, 3 });
   vector<int> vec2;
   copy2(vec.begin(), vec.end(), back_inserter(vec2));
   for (int i : vec2)
   {
      cout << i << endl;
   }
}
```

Which takes quite a long to compile, but will finally do with the proper output

```
1
2
3
```

The problem is (*without knowing the inner implementation of `std::vector`, is it `c-style` array? or more complex structure?*), how can it properly *find* those elements in the `for(int i:vec2)`, when the address (pointers) of those elements are *not* sequential? (i.e. *because of the shifting of the iterator/pointer by `99999999`*).

I thought there was a requirement for `OutputIterator` to have that property, that only one-access, one-shift could be performed on it. But when you shift(add) it more than once between accessing them, then there is a gap, which is quite huge in my case. So how does it compile?

Comment: @Graham a vector gives you a pointer to a C-style array from `data()`, but it can resize it in place (up to capacity) without affecting the existing elements. Prior to C++20, that requires implementation-defined magic

Comment: @Caleth It is *permitted* to resize it in place, which in practise means allocating successively larger arrays with space to grow up to some limit before more allocation is needed. Because the underlying storage is defined to be a contiguous C-style array, resizing may need a new allocation and copy, so you can't rely on pointers staying valid after resizing.

Comment: @Graham I don't mean reallocating, but a `vector<T>` with capacity >= 5 can hand out a pointer to a `T[4]`, have an element inserted, then hand out a pointer to a `T[5]` with the same address as the `T[4]`. Somehow it has to destroy the `T[4]` and construct a `T[5]` without affecting the elements

Comment: @Caleth After inserting, the address of T[5] could theoretically be same as the previous T[4] depending on implementation; but it could equally well be completely the other end of memory. Pointers to internal storage become invalid after any resize operation, so after you do the insert, you'd need to find the new address of that T[5] element. That's why all the resize operations have the side effect of invalidating all iterators. You're guaranteed that the *data* in the previous T[4] will be in T[5] after insertion, but not where that data lives in memory.

Comment: @Graham I'm not talking about reallocating. I'm talking about the case where you insert an element and it *doesn't* reallocate. There is an array object of one size, which is transmuted into an array object of another size. I say transmuted, because C++ doesn't have a way of doing that. As a concrete example `std::vector<int> vec { 1, 2, 3 }; vec.reserve(8); auto * ptr1 = vec.data(); vec.push_back(4); auto * ptr2 = vec.data();` Here `ptr1` is initialised pointing to an `int[3]`, and `ptr2` is pointing to an `int[4]`, but they have the same value.

Comment: @Graham or `std::vector<int> vec { 1, 2, 3 }; auto * p1 = vec.data(); vec.pop_back()`. The implementation has to transmute the object that p1 points into from an `int[3]` to an `int[2]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219039/discussion-between-caleth-and-graham).

Comment: I think you confuse “compile” with “execute”.

Comment: @CarstenS even if it was "execute", a `-O3` compiled program will ran in under 3ms on my machine & profiler couldn't even catch anything that the program does.

Comment: @ankii, I did not check how long it should take to execute the loop, but the answers indicate that it will be optimised away anyway.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You've been fooled.

The iterator returned by `std::back_inserter` has [`it++` as a no-op](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator/operator%2B%2B). So those 'gaps' you are creating? Yeah that's all doing nothing.

Comment: But clearly, OP knew there was no gap, they did print the vector... It's really unclear what they thought they were doing with this loop.

Comment: @Jeffrey My interpretation of their premise is that the gaps are there somewhere, and there is a pointer somewhere, and the pointer jumps over the gaps, which pointers aren't supposed to do.

Comment: They also have the problem that if it did reallocate the array to create a gap, then all their pointers and iterators would become invalid and their code would throw an exception. So it can only run by not working as expected. :)

Answer (score 22):

> std::vector, is it c-style array?

Not quite, but the buffer that it creates is structurally identical.

> when the address (pointers) of those element are not sequential?

The premise is faulty. The memory addresses of vector elements are contiguous. One object begins immediately after another.

Also, whether they are sequential or not doesn't matter. You can equally well iterate over a linked list even though those elements are not contiguous in memory.

> OutputIterator ... But when you shift(add) it more then once between accessing them, then there is a gap

This assumption is not true.

In particular case of `std::back_insert_iterator`, the documentation says:

> ```
> std::back_insert_iterator<Container>::operator++
> ```
>
> Does nothing.

Answer (score 22):

Your for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 99999999; i++)
{
    dest++;
}
```

does not do what you think. It has no effect on there, other than iterating from `0` to `99999999`.

When you look into the [`std::back_insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator), it says

> [...]. **Incrementing the `std::back_insert_iterator` is a no-op.**

or as stated in [23.5.2.1.1](http://eel.is/c++draft//predef.iterators#back.insert.iter.ops-7) it simply returns the `back_insert_iterator`, without doing anything into it.

> ```
> constexpr back_insert_iterator& operator++();
> constexpr back_insert_iterator  operator++(int);
>
> #Returns: *this.
> ```

Meaning `dest++;` has no effect. This makes entire assumptions you made, completely not valid. The program took long to execute only because of the iteration from `0` to `99999999`.

---

It raises the question: Then why there is an `std::back_insert_iterator<Container>::operator++` overload at all?

From cpprefereence [`std::back_insert_iterator<Container>::operator++`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator/operator%2B%2B):

> Does nothing. These operator overloads are provided **to satisfy the
> requirements of
> [LegacyOutputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator)**.
> They make it possible for the expressions `*iter++=value` and
> `*++iter=value` to be used to output (insert) a value into the
> underlying container.